# Trying to Install a Physical HDD on Physical Server, MS 2008 R2

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Physcial Server that has 6 HD Bays on it.  I have put in 4 NEW 1TB HDD's today, filling up the remaining 4 slots.  The BIOS Says the drives are "Ready" but I cannot force them into Online mode, and I cannot find anything on the Microsoft Server Help telling me how to get the server to show these new drives, or at least the space contained in the new drives.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are the other two configured in a raid?  Are you looking to add the new ones to said raid?  What are you planning to do with the new drives.

Comment: I am new to this job, so I am assuming alot because the previous IT guy here left without warning and didnt leave me any materials to really go on.  Im sure they are RAID Drives, and I am trying to add them to it, yes.  I have never done this before and am not all that familiar with it.

Comment: Ok, lets assume they are RAID'D.  Since there are only two they are either a RAID 0 or 1.  If you are looking to expand the RAID, it will depend on the features of your RAID controller if that is possible.  What are your options in the RAID controller?  In case you don't know what a RAID is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID

Comment: Ok, Im sorry, I was rooting around in the system and I see that the controller for all the HDD is SCSI, Im not sure if that makes a difference here or not.  I know the Drives are SATA

Comment: Ryan E is definitely right about RAID. When you boot the server, does it prompt you for the option to configure RAID as it is cycling through RAID (if its there), network controllers...etc etc. You will likely need to configure them on the RAID system before being able to mount the drives.

Comment: So, I guess teh fact that the thing says SCSI instead of RAID doesnt matter?

Comment: During your BIOS boot do you see an option to enter the RAID configuration?

Comment: Yes, Ctrl -R I believe is the stroke to get into it, and I got in there, and it showed me the four drives as Ready, but When I tried to put them in online mode the mode was greyed out, only an option to Make Global HS, which I did not use to make sure I didnt do anything wrong before I asked someone who knew.